# I want that onCreate of my activity will be called every time that my broadcast receiver launches it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

I have a broadcast receiver which start an activity on its `onReceive` with the following flag : `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Now, the `onCreate` method of my activity gets called. When I click on the HOME button, my activity moves back to background but now when the `onReceive` function will be called again, the `onRestart` method will be called instead of the `onCreate`.

I want that `onCreate` will be called on every `onReceive` (I need the same behavior for every event that my broadcast receiver received).

Another thing, my activity (the one that gets launched by the broadcast receiver have this flag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`.

I done this to prevent a way that clicking on my app icon will launch my activity (its not the main activity).

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: What is it that you are doing in the onCreate on your Activity? Starting an activity from the receiver will disturb user as he/she might be in the middle of something more important.

Comment: I'm showing the user two buttons and starts a countdown to 10 seconds

Comment: Try this flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK with the one you already use

Comment: tried it, it didn't work

Comment: Actually, you don't really care whether onCreate is called.  Why don't you abstract the code that you want called from both onReceive and on Create into a new method, and call it from each...

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. You can start your timer in onResume(). Everytime the Activity is called started again, if it's already running, you can remove the Runnable from the handler queue and start it again. You don't need the specify launchMode of the Activity in manifest.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean isBroadcastHandled = false;
    private int mCounter = 10;

    private final Runnable runnableThatRunsEvery1Sec = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Update Your TimerTextView
            if(mCounter == 0){
                // Send SMS accordingly.
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            mCounter-- ;
        }
    };

    // Set Up Click listener for Buttons too

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!isBroadcastHandled){
            // Set Your Time Text View to 10 here.
            mHandler.post(runnableThatRunsEvery1Sec);
            isBroadcastHandled = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        isBroadcastHandled = false;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnableThatRunsEvery1Sec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnableThatRunsEvery1Sec);
    }
}
```

Comment: but onResume will get called after every onPause and onRestart. it means that if the user pressed the home button and then clicked on my app from the task mgr, he will get a new count which I don't want.

Comment: That Runnable is run on the UI thread. I am still not very sure what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'll explain. I want to start an activity from broadcast receiver. This activity will have two buttons and a countdowntimer. If the user clicks on one of the buttons, I'm sending an SMS containing X. If the countdowntimer expires I'm sending an SMS containing Y.